# Nodejs how to separate multiple "multipartform-data" POST requests

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multipartform-data

In Nodejs I have developed a small Client application that sends multiple “multipart/form-data” to my Server application using POST requests.
Each form to be sent is composed by a file (loaded from the Client hard-disk) and a string information. Basically I have the following situation :

Form 1: (File 1, String 1)
Form 2: (File 2, String 2)
Form 3: (File 3, String 3)
Etc..

To make the POST requests I’m using the “form-data” library ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data ).
The problem that I’m facing is that all the POST requests are sent after the end of the execution of my Client application, but I would like to be able to send each POST request separately.

Here is a part of the code that I’m using :

```
function FormSubmit(item)
{
     var FileStream = fs.createReadStream(item.path);                

     // Create an "Upload" Form and set all form parameters.
     let form = new FormData();             

     form.append('Text1', 'test');
     form.append('file', FileStream);     

     // Form Submit.
     form.submit('http://localhost:5000/upload', function(err, res) {
          if (err) {
               console.log(err);
          }
          if (res!= undefined)
               res.resume();
          else
               console.log('Res undefined: ', res);
     });
}
```

I’m calling the “FormSubmit” function multiple times, and I was expecting to receive the POST request on the Server application every time after executing the command “form.submit”, but in reality I receive the POST requests all together after the entire application execution finish. 
In particular the Server receives the requests on the command “self.emit('connect');” inside the function “afterConnect” in the “net.js” file in the core module.

It seems that it has nothing to do with timings, because even if i put a breakpoint and wait for some minutes after the first execution of the "FormSubmit" function, i don't receive anything on the Server application.
Probably it is not something related to the "form-data" library, because i get the same behaviour using "request", etc..
I guess it is something related to NodeJs itself or about how i wrote the Client application.

I am new to NodeJs so any help/advice would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: create different form for each file upload.

Comment: i guess i'm already creating a different form, since i'm calling "FormSubmit" multiple times, and inside that function there is "let form = new FormData();".

Comment: Try with async await for this. that may help you.

Comment: Do you mean to modify it as : async function FormSubmit(item) ... let response = await form.submit('http://localhost:5000/upload', ...) ?    If so, it didn't solve my problem.